# How to disable PHP's SSL verification for self-signed at server/ini level?

Tags: php, docker, apache, ssl, curl

In my docker dev environment, I have a php-fpm container which runs cURL commands to other local docker development domains (ie: mysite.dev.local).

I've setup Apache to serve SSL, with certs created by mkcert on these servers. However, PHP's cURL is complaining about self-signed certs.

I know adding the following will skip the ssl verificaiton:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

However, I don't wish to write code in for this as it will eventually be used in a live production level where SSL is important.

I've also tried to setup cacert.pem (https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html) and setting it in my php.ini, however it returns the following error:

> SSL Certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate.

I don't understand why that doesn't work, is it a conflict with Apache using certs? I've confirmed it's setup using phpinfo().

Snippet from docker-compose.yml:

```
  fpm:
    build: ./docker/php-fpm
    links:
      - "db"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/php-fpm/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ./docker/php-fpm/cacert.pem:/etc/php/cacert.pem
```

php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 25M
log_errors = on
error_reporting = E_ALL
error_log = /var/log/php-fpm.log
post_max_size = 25M
memory_limit = 1024M
short_open_tag = off
curl.cainfo = /etc/php/cacert.pem
openssl.cafile = /etc/php/cacert.pem
```

[image]

When I run curl from command line in the container to one of my dev evironment domains, I get the following:

> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
> certificate More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could
> not establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this
> situation and how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned
> above.

I was wondering if there was a way at php.ini/server level which I can include in my docker container build to tell php/curl to always ignore SSL as it's only used for local development?

Comment: Curl doesn't have INI settings for SSL validation, so you'd have to do it at runtime. You could inject an env var like `APP_ENV=dev` or `APP_ENV=prod`, then conditionally disable/enable SSL validation based on that.

Comment: What are the perms on that `/etc/php/cacert.pem` file?

Comment: Ditto for using a dev/prod variable as it will likely be useful for more than just this.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling SSL verification in PHP at the server or php.ini level.

But remember that  should never be used in a production environment.

So if you want to do it in the development environment you can do it in 2 ways:

Edit php.ini

Add the following lines to your php.ini file:

[curl]
curl.cainfo = "path/to/cacert.pem"

Replace "path/to/cacert.pem" with the actual path to your cacert.pem file. This tells PHP to use this certificate file for SSL.

Ok, I know, it will not really disable SSL verification but it will tell the  PHP which CA certificate to trust (your self-signed certificate in this case).

After making changes to php.ini, restart your PHP service to apply these changes.

Or if you are using docker, you can do it in your Docker setup, go to your Dockerfile or docker-compose file:

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:fpm
...
ENV CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/path/to/cacert.pem
...
```

Or in a docker-compose.yml:

services:

```
  php-fpm:
    ...
    environment:
      - CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/path/to/cacert.pem
    ...
```

Again, replace /path/to/cacert.pem with the actual path to your cacert.pem file.

Or you also can use a script to do it:

```
// curl-config.php
if (getenv('ENVIRONMENT') === 'development') {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
}
```

include this script in your PHP files where you're using cURL.

```
require 'path/to/curl-config.php';
```

But again,  disabling SSL verification is a significant security risk. Make sure this is only done in a controlled development environment.

Comment: Is there a way to configure PHP to include that `curl-config.php` file before everything for every PHP script?

Comment: if you are using a framework, consider use a customClass, but really depends how you are doing your code..